# Which RxJS type to use when a method may or may not fetch data asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs

Imagine we have the following factory:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataClassFactory {

constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
) { }

public createThing(initialData?: InitialData): AsyncSubject<DataClass> {
    let dataClass: AsyncSubject<DataClass> = new AsyncSubject<DataClass>();
    if (!!initialData) {
        dataClass.next(new DataClass(initialData));
        dataClass.complete();
    } else {
            this.dataService.getData().subscribe((dataResponse) => {
                dataClass.next(new ReportRequest(dataResponse));
                dataClass.complete();
            });
        }
    }
    return dataClass;
}
```

}

We inject this factory, invoke the createThing method, and subscribe to the response in some component.  I originally tried to use a plain Subject, but then I realized that in the case where we already have initial data, next() is called before the response is returned, so the subscriber in the component never gets that value.

My question is: is this correct situation in which to use an AsyncSubject, or is there a different/better way to handle this sort of method that has potential synchronous and asynchronous timelines?

Comment: use the observables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something along these lines

```
public createThing(initialData?: InitialData): Observable<DataClass | ReportRequest> {
    if (!!initialData) {
        const data = new DataClass(initialData);
        return of(data);
    } else {
            return this.dataService.getData()
                           .pipe(map(dataResponse => new ReportRequest(dataResponse));
    }
}
```

Whoever calls createThing would get an Observable to which it would have to subscribe.

This Observable would emit an instance of `DataClass` if `initialData` is not null, otherwise it would return and instance of `ReportRequest` as soon as `dataService` responds.

Comment: Ah, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.  I knew there was a more straightforward way to do this, I was just in the mindset that the service call had to return a subscription.  I forgot about pipe.  Thank you.

Comment: @ace If it answers your question, you should do Picci the favor of marking it as accepted (and potentially upvote it). For what it's worth, this is the correct solution in my opinion as well.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the reminder.  I got busy testing the solution in my project and forgot to circle back to accept.